# Which Kitchen outlets do NOT need GFCI?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, receptacle, gfci, outlets

I have the 2 circuits in the kitchen with GFCI outlets, but I'm not quite sure which other ones do NOT need GFCI. Other circuits in the kitchen include Microwave, Fridge, and Dishwasher. It makes sense to me to not have the fridge on GFCI though.

Comment: At one point, only outdoor outlets needed GFCI protection. Over the years, the NEC has required protection at more and more locations. So whether your installation meets the requirements depends on which version of the NEC was in effect when the work was initiated.

Comment: NEC 2014 requires either GFCI or AFCI protection for 99% of **all** the normal outlets in your home. [Where *shouldn't* I use GFCI/AFCI?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/75011/23295)

Answer (score 15):

The NEC (NFPA 70 2011 edition) requires GFCI receptacles in kitchens of dwelling units where the receptacles are installed to serve the countertop surfaces. It does not mention a distance requirement in kitchens.

The distance requirement of 1.8 meters (6 feet) is for sinks located in areas other than kitchens.

Section 210.8 A of NFPA 70 2011 Edition deals with GFCI protection in dwelling units (see below).

> **210.8 Ground-Fault Circuit-Interrupter Protection for Personnel.**
>
> Ground-fault circuit-interruption for personnel shall be provided as
> required in 210.8(A) through (C). The ground-fault circuit-interrupter
> shall be installed in a readily accessible location. Informational
> Note: See 215.9 for ground-fault circuit-interrupter protection for
> personnel on feeders.
>
> **(A)  Dwelling Units.**   All 125-volt, single-phase, 15- and 20-ampere receptacles installed in the locations specified in 210.8(A)(1)
> through (8) shall have ground-fault circuit-interrupter protection for
> personnel
>
> (1) Bathrooms
>
> (2) Garages, and also accessory buildings that have a floor located at
> or below grade level not intended as habitable rooms and limited to
> storage areas, work areas, and areas of similar use.
>
> (3) Outdoors
> *Exception to (3): Receptacles that are not readily accessible and are supplied by a branch circuit dedicated to electric snow-melting,
> deicing, or pipeline and vessel heating equipment shall be permitted
> to be installed in accordance with 426.28 or 427.22, as applicable.*
>
> (4) Crawl spaces — at or below grade level
>
> (5) Unfinished basements — for purposes of this section, unfinished
> basements are defined as portions or areas of the basement not
> intended as habitable rooms and limited to storage areas, work areas,
> and the like
> *Exception to (5): A receptacle supplying only a permanently installed fire alarm or burglar alarm system shall not be required to have
> ground-fault circuit-interrupter protection.*
>
> *Informational Note: See 760.41(B) and 760.121(B) for power supply requirements for fire alarm systems.*
>
> Receptacles installed under the exception to 210.8(A)(5) shall not be
> considered as meeting the requirements of 210.52(G).
>
> (6) Kitchens—
> where the receptacles are installed to serve the countertop surfaces
>
> (7) Sinks — located in areas other than kitchens where receptacles are
> installed within 1.8 m (6 ft) of the outside edge of the sink
>
> (8)
> Boathouses

Comment: Can you find the section that address this?  It seems like you might have a copy and I could not find a free one online easily.  +1 anyway.

Comment: @auujay  Added Reference section to the answer.

Comment: Why is it any outlet that serves a countertop?

Technically any outlet could serve a countertop. I wish the requirement was more specific and said why.

Answer (score 11):

All outlets that support convenience plug in items within 8 feet of a water source must be GFI protected.  However, the new NEC calls for a separate non GFI circuit (home run) for the fridge or other fixed appliances. These non protected circuits must be single purpose and wired to a single outlet or direct wired and dedicated to the appliance. This can include dishwashers, garbage diposers, vent fans, most permanent motor loads.

Comment: Any guess why the NEC requires them each to have a dedicated circuit?

Comment: My "guess" is that motor loads often trip GFI's on start up and shut down, due to inductive kick. This nuisance tripping was a constant source of consumer complaints. Since the cases of these fixed appliances are almost always metal and grounded, there was no reason to protect them in the first place. The NEC didn't consult with me personally, but I figure this may have been some of the reasoning. lol.

Comment: Does there need to be a seperate circuit for each appliacnce, or could the dishwasher and disposer, for instance, be on the same circuit?

Comment: Except for a fridge, range and ovens, I believe you can group other appliances such as a dishwasher and disposer.  Hoping one of the Code Book guys can give a reference.  Guess I better go buy my own copy. Haven't consulted with my electrician on those details.  I am trying to get him on here to handle these questions.

Comment: It's actually six feet (which covers the arm span of most adults that don't play professional basketball). If you can hold on to a sink and touch it, it needs to be GFCI protected. Overkill here, however, is never a bad thing :)

Comment: Unfortunately there is much wrong with this answer. Considering the date, the old 6' rule (NOT 8') to a sink was already removed. ALL receptacles serving counter spaces require GFI protection. There is NO requirement that a fridge be dedicated, although it is a good idea. Also, things like a DW and disp CAN share a circuit and do NOT require a single receptacle. Some appliances that are heavy draw and fixed in place, like an over-the-range micro do typically require a dedicated circuit. Also, keep in mind the date of this answer. Under the 2014 NEC a DW DOES now require GFI protection.

Comment: No grouping of fixed appliances - they need to be dedicated.  This answer is incorrect in that the water distance spoken of is for those sources not in the kitchen or the bathroom - such as a laundry sink. Kitchen counter top outlets  (IOW expected to be used by people at various times )  should be GFCI. Others like a disposer and dw and Refrigerator outlet no GFCI.

Answer (score 6):

According to the 2014 version of the National Electrical Code, all 120 volt, single phase, 15 and 20 ampere receptacles in dwelling units, serving coutertop surfaces are required to have ground-fault protection for personnel.

So any other kitchen receptacle, would not *require* GFCI protection.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 2 Wiring and Protection
>
> #### Article 210 Branch Circuits
>
> **210.8 Ground-Fault Circuit-Interrupter Protection for
>   Personnel.**
>
> **(A) Dwelling Units.** All 125-volt, single-phase, 15- and
>   20-ampere receptacles installed in the locations specified in
>   210.8(A)(1) through (10) shall have ground-fault circuitinterrupter
>   protection for personnel.
>
> (6) Kitchens— where the receptacles are installed to
>   serve the countertop surfaces

Comment: My landlord refuses to install a GFCI receptacle in our kitchen on our backsplash. The maintenance person they brought over said that the outlet is grounded, and that's good enough. Clearly that's not the case, or else I wouldn't have a GFCI receptacle with the reset button in the bathroom. Is there any free URL you could point me to with this code so I can force them to follow code?

Comment: @EHorodyski I'm not sure if there's a free source.  Your local building department, or local library (if libraries still exist) should have a copy.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm a dope. I work for the IEEE, and we have the standards/handbook on our search platform. Although the newest version I can find is 2014, is that still valid?

Comment: @EHorodyski Yes, 2014 is the most recent edition. However, not all areas have adopted 2014, so some still follow older versions of the code.

Comment: Thank you again. One last question if you don't mind and have an answer; as a tenant in an apartment complex, is the complex required to adopt the most recent edition? Does it vary by state or county? Sorry to keep bugging you, but you're very knowledgeable in this area. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: @EHorodyski I'm not sure how it works in rental units.  In single family dwellings, you typically only have to update electrical if you're doing work to the system. In multi-family dwellings, some upgrades might be required before renting a unit. Though what upgrades are required, is likely dependant on the local government.

Comment: @EHorodyski You should be able to contact your local government, and find out what's required, and when.

Comment: @EHorodyski The landlord may be right.  If there is GFCI protection for that receptacle *upstream*, then he doesn't need a "GFCI+receptacle combo device" at that location. Stick a GFCI tester in there, hit the button and see if it trips.  Then the hard part comes: Finding the reset!

Comment: @Harper -- Thanks! I'm not even living there anymore! My new abode has nice fixtures with reset switches and everything.

Comment: @Tester101 I know it is an old post here (don't know why it is not marked answer either), landlords of single family rentals - when built unless modified or remodeled - EXCEPTION is for section 8 tenant, HUD requires modifications - such as true grounding of all outlets. Multi unit dwellings depending on classification can fall in to the same requirements as single family dwelling. Apartments I am not sure on - but I believe they too fall into the same category upgrade on remodel but ordinary use no requirements - unless there is a specific state, county/parish/burrough, city requirement.

Answer (score -4):

Another reason the NEC probably didn't require GFCI on dedicated appliances like refrigerators and dishwashers is that many manufacturers had previously connected the neutral and ground wire together in which some electrical current may return to the source through the ground wire tripping GFCIs. I believed UL required this at one point. I don't know if newer appliances still have this.

Most electrical fixtures and appliances these days are double insulated and usually don’t have a problem. Just be aware that not all 3-wire appliances will work properly when directly plugged into a GFCI circuit.

Comment: Not true at all. ALL 120V grounding appliances should work FINE on a GFI protected circuit/receptacle. These appliances NEVER combined the ground and neutral. This was only the case in 120/240V household cooking appliances and electric dryers.

Comment: Refrigerators, Dishwashers had motors with large current draw - GFCI was originally known to be flakey in circuits with motors like these. Connecting Ground and Neutral together is a no-no as the frame can become hot in certain circumstances. As Petey said - that was done on dryers and ranges (3 wire systems) and it was dangerous - which is why the code requires them to be 4 wire systems. Ground, Neutral and L1, L2.