# Why does this kitchen receptacle located on the far side, away from the sink, need to be GFCI?

Tags: gfci, kitchen-counters

According to this answer, all receptacles in a kitchen that serve a countertop surface must be GFCI protected.

[Which Kitchen outlets do NOT need GFCI?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9341/which-kitchen-outlets-do-not-need-gfci)

I already replaced the outlets next to the sink with gfci and will now replace an outlet located on the opposite side of the kitchen sink, so my understanding is that I must replace with a gfci (and tamper resistant too?). I have no problems following code, but I'd rather understand the reasoning behind code. Why does this receptacle need to be gfci protected if it is far away from the sink?

[image]

Comment: Is the intent of that area to prepare food or drink?  I think you imagine that GFCI is there only to defend against a single risk, touching appliance and sink simultaneously. That is certainly an obvious use-case for GFCI, but hardly the only one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Is that outlet in the kitchen, or is it in the dining area? If it's in the dining area, it might not need GFCI.)

The reasoning I'd give is that kitchen outlets are much more likely to be dealing with water than other outlets, even if they're nowhere near the sink. You could have a coffeemaker, or slow cooker, or microwave, or bread maker plugged in there, all of which can have both water and electricity in the same appliance, which increases the possibility of electric shock.

Comment: Good explanation. We have used the far-from-kitchen-sink outlet for a coffee machine and microwave oven in the past.